# STM3210 USB to serial adapter not showing up in /dev/ttyUSB

Tags: drivers, usb, serial-port

I found a vinyl cutter on Ebay, and purchased it.

Then I stumbled upon this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tZXsUGEJ-E which demonstrates that it is possible to use this type of device on linux. I have installed inkcut, but cannot quite figure out how to connect to the device.

`lsusb -v` gives this for the device:

```
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0483:5750 STMicroelectronics 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0483 STMicroelectronics
  idProduct          0x5750 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           39
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Bidirectional
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval             255
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

and `dmesg` gives this output:

```
[ 3775.238980] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 3775.388610] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5750
[ 3775.388619] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3775.388624] usb 3-3: Product: STM32 USB DEVICE  
[ 3775.388628] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: XILI
[ 3775.388632] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: STM3210
[ 3775.391026] usblp 3-3:1.0: usblp2: USB Bidirectional printer dev 10 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x0483 pid 0x5750
```

... when I plug in the device. (This is a clean capture after doing `sudo dmesg -C`)

`/var/log/syslog` output:

```
Jan  9 21:48:58 Touchy kernel: [ 4124.339691] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
Jan  9 21:48:58 Touchy kernel: [ 4124.488804] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5750
Jan  9 21:48:58 Touchy kernel: [ 4124.488808] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan  9 21:48:58 Touchy kernel: [ 4124.488810] usb 3-3: Product: STM32 USB DEVICE  
Jan  9 21:48:58 Touchy kernel: [ 4124.488812] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: XILI
Jan  9 21:48:58 Touchy kernel: [ 4124.488814] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: STM3210
Jan  9 21:48:58 Touchy kernel: [ 4124.492479] usblp 3-3:1.0: usblp2: USB Bidirectional printer dev 11 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x0483 pid 0x5750
Jan  9 21:48:58 Touchy mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 11: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3"
Jan  9 21:48:58 Touchy mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 11 was not an MTP device
Jan  9 21:48:58 Touchy upowerd[932]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0
Jan  9 21:48:58 Touchy upowerd[932]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3
Jan  9 21:50:27 Touchy kernel: [ 4213.279883] perf: interrupt took too long (3164 > 3126), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63000
```

I have read a lot of different articles online, some mentioning [udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html), etc, but no matter what, a `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*` returns `ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB*': No such file or directory`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was not what I thought it was.

I figured out that the printer is showing up as a USB LP device (usblp2) connected at `/dev/usb/lp2`. This meant that I had to select Parallel port. this did not appear directly in inkcut, but required a reboot.